# iframe is not working in my website?

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

website link: http://www.edvinci.com/5w-series
[image]

```
<div class="col-md-7">
 <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1LcfTViHQiQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

error:
[image]

1.Refused to frame 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKWXMZUbIvo' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Maybe this helps ► [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092858/refused-to-frame-https-www-youtube-com-embed-xxxxx-because-it-violates-conten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092858/refused-to-frame-https-www-youtube-com-embed-xxxxx-because-it-violates-conten)

Comment: Can you please share the link of your site..

Comment: http://www.edvinci.com/5w-series